# Pandas variance and Standard deviation result differing with manual calculation

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, standard-deviation, variance

I'm trying to fin Mean, Variance and SD using pandas.  However, manual calcuation is different from that of pandas output. is there anything i'm missing using pandas.  Attached the xl screenshot for reference[image: Mean=394, Variance21704, SD=147.32]

```
import pandas as pd

dg_df = pd.DataFrame(
            data=[600,470,170,430,300],
            index=['a','b','c','d','e'])

print(dg_df.mean(axis=0)) # 394.0 matches with manual calculation
print(dg_df.var())        # 27130.0 not matching with manual calculation 21704
print(dg_df.std(axis=0))  # 164.71187 not matching with manual calculation 147.32
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change default parameter `ddof=1` (Delta Degrees of Freedom) to `0` in [`DataFrame.var`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.var.html) and also in [`DataFrame.std`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.std.html), parameter `axis=0` is default, so should be omitted:

```
print(dg_df.mean())
0    394.0
dtype: float64

print(dg_df.var(ddof=0))  
0    21704.0
dtype: float64

print(dg_df.std(ddof=0))
0    147.322775
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 6):

There is more than one definition of standard deviation. You are calculating the equivalent of Excel `STDEV.P`, which has the description: "Calculates standard deviation based on the entire **population**...". If you need sample standard deviation in Excel use `STDEV.S`.

[`pd.DataFrame.std`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.std.html) assumes 1 *degree of freedom* by default, also known as **sample** standard deviation.

[`numpy.std`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.std.html) assumes 0 *degree of freedom* by default, also known as **population** standard deviation.

See [**Bessel's correction**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel%27s_correction) to understand the difference between sample and population.

You can also specify `ddof=0` with Pandas `std` / `var` methods:

```
dg_df.std(ddof=0)
dg_df.var(ddof=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You also can use dg_df.describe(), then have next dataframe. Maybe more visual

```
count   5.00000
mean    394.00000
std 164.71187
min 170.00000
25% 300.00000
50% 430.00000
75% 470.00000
max 600.00000
```

And you can get the right data like `dg_df.describe().loc['count']`